# How to save model relationships with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following model:

```
App.Loan = DS.Model.extend
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('App.Product')
```

Then on my code I'm calling `save` method on a Loan object, which has many products associated, but only the loan gets posted to the server, the associated objects do not.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking at the code, it seems this is intended, because calling save on a record would add this record, and only this record in the current transaction. The associated objects are also added if they are embedded.

In your case, I would first create a new transaction, adding the record and the associated objects, and then calling commit on this transaction. Something like

```
var transaction = store.transaction();
transaction.add(loan)
loan.get('products').forEach(function(product)){
  transaction.add(product);
});
transaction.commit()
```

If you want to embed the products in the loan, you can do it by configuring the adapter like this. Assuming you are using the default REST Adapter:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Loan', {
   products: { embedded: always }
}
```

Comment: If I do that the my products do not get associated to the loan in the server, because they are sent by themselves.

Comment: So, I think you want to embed the products in the loan.